# simple past continuous combined with "for"

Tags: past-continuous

I am going to make up three sentences below.

(1) Three weeks ago, I **was** writing a short essay **for** five days.

(2) John **was** scoring a lot of goals **for** many years.

(3) During Tim's one-week stay in my home, I **was** working on my project **for** five days.

I am using the past continuous tense because the action mentioned in each sentence happened over a period of time. Does this tense work in my examples?

Answer (score 1):

One sentence suffers from clarity issues, while each of them could be cleaned up to sound more natural, as well as for readability.

Regarding your first sentence:

- **Three weeks ago, I was writing a short essay for five days.**

This is essentially clear. There's not much else it could mean beyond there being a point in the recent past during which you spent a five-day period of time working on an essay.

Written more naturally, it would be:

> **Three weeks ago, I spent five days writing a short essay.**

Or:

> **Three weeks ago, it took me five days to write a short essay.**

As for sentence number two:

- **John was scoring a lot of goals for many years.**

This one needs some clarity. Are you trying to say that John was a big goal-scorer before, but now things are different? Are you saying John scored a lot of goals until something happened to change that? It's not obvious what the sentence is trying to say, but here are some options for a rewrite:

> **For many years, John scored a lot of goals.**

Or:

> **For many years, John had been scoring a lot of goals—until...**

Or:

> **John had scored many goals over the years.**

Without context, though, it's impossible to determine which best communicates your intent.

And then, sentence number three:

- **During Tim's one-week stay in my home, I was working on my project
  for five days.**

Again, this one's pretty clear, but awkwardly worded, which impedes its effectiveness.

A different option:

> **During Tim's one-week stay in my home, I spent five days working on my**
>   **project**.

Or:

> **The week Tim stayed with me, I spent five days working on my**
>   **project**.